# How to let an animation finish before the next userinput is allowed

Tags: iphone, animation, timer, uiimage, sleep

I have some UIImageViews and when the user is touching, an animation with a certain duration starts. A trigger counts ++ and with the next touch another animation starts to play.
But if the user touches to fast or make a doubletouch the first animation does not finish until the last frame. 
I tried the "sleep()" command, but it does not work.

```
    #pragma mark HenneAnimation
    if([touch view] == ani_Henne){

        //trigger strats with zero
        switch (trigHenne) {
            case 0:
//firstanimation 1 sec
                ani_Henne.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne01.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne01.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne02.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne01.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne01.png"],nil];


                ani_Henne.animationDuration = 1;
                ani_Henne.animationRepeatCount = 1;
                [ani_Henne startAnimating];
                [self.view addSubview:ani_Henne];

                trigHenne++;
                break;

            case 1:
//second animation 1 sec                
                ani_Henne.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne03.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne05.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne03.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne03.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne04.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne05.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne03.png"],nil];              
                ani_Henne.animationDuration = 3;
                ani_Henne.animationRepeatCount = 1;
            [ani_Henne startAnimating];
                [self.view addSubview:ani_Henne];

                trigHenne++;

                break;

            case 2:
                [self.view bringSubviewToFront:ani_Henne];

                ani_Henne.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne06.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne07.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne06.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne06.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne08.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne08.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne09.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne08.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne09.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne08.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne07.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne08.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne09.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ani_Henne08.png"],nil];

                ani_Henne.animationDuration = 2.75;
            ani_Henne.animationRepeatCount = 1;
                [ani_Henne startAnimating];
                [self.view addSubview:ani_Henne];

                trigHenne++;
                break;
            case 3:
                trigHenne=0;
// etc. animations
                break;
            default:
                break;  
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you begin to animate set the userinteraction disabled, and when you are done, reenable it like:

yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

you could also delay the enabling with

```
...
[self performSelector:@selector(enable) withObject:yourImageView afterDelay:1.0];
...


-(void)enable
{
yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES
}
```

Comment: Thank You, it works like I want it!
It's better and easier than the beginIgnoringInteractionEvents-solution, because only the choosen View is disabled for input!

Answer (score 0):

Using UIApplications beginIgnoringInteractionEvents and endIgnoringInteractionEvents might help you, when begin is called UI interaction events from user are ignored, here is a reference [UIApplication ref](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginIgnoringInteractionEvents)

Comment: I've done it like this:

case 0:
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
   {
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut]; //geschmeidige Bewegeung
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0f];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];

    ani_schwein_gross.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (-200, 10);
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(doneSwappingViewsAnimation:finished:context:)];
   }
    [UIView commitAnimations];

etc.

The animation finish - and any input is disabled.

Comment: before ViewDIdLoad I inserted:

- (void) doneSwappingViewsAnimation: (NSString*) id
finished: (BOOL) finished context: (id) context
{
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
}